# Object Array Logic Issue

Tags: java, arrays

I am fairly new to java programming, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock with how I should create these objects in a game I'm making.

Here's a sample of code:

```
public static Sprite backwardNullHelm           = new Sprite(16, 0, 0, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite backwardNullHelm_1         = new Sprite(16, 1, 0, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite backwardNullHelm_2         = new Sprite(16, 2, 0, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite forwardNullHelm            = new Sprite(16, 0, 1, SpriteSheet.armor); 
public static Sprite forwardNullHelm_1          = new Sprite(16, 1, 1, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite forwardNullHelm_2          = new Sprite(16, 2, 1, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite rightNullHelm              = new Sprite(16, 0, 2, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite rightNullHelm_1            = new Sprite(16, 1, 2, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite rightNullHelm_2            = new Sprite(16, 2, 2, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite leftNullHelm               = new Sprite(16, 0, 3, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite leftNullHelm_1             = new Sprite(16, 1, 3, SpriteSheet.armor);
public static Sprite leftNullHelm_2             = new Sprite(16, 2, 3, SpriteSheet.armor);
```

This is how I'm declaring sprites for the character's headgear.
Here's the constructor if necessary:

```
public Sprite(int size, int x, int y, SpriteSheet sheet)
```

I'm storing them in arrays like this:

```
backwardHelmet[0] = Sprite.backwardNullHelm;
backwardHelmet[1] = Sprite.backwardNullHelm_1;
backwardHelmet[2] = Sprite.backwardNullHelm_2;
forwardHelmet[0]  = Sprite.forwardNullHelm;
forwardHelmet[1]  = Sprite.forwardNullHelm_1;
forwardHelmet[2]  = Sprite.forwardNullHelm_2;
rightHelmet[0]    = Sprite.rightNullHelm;
rightHelmet[1]    = Sprite.rightNullHelm_1;
rightHelmet[2]    = Sprite.rightNullHelm_2;
leftHelmet[0]     = Sprite.leftNullHelm;
leftHelmet[1]     = Sprite.leftNullHelm_1;
leftHelmet[2]     = Sprite.leftNullHelm_2;
```

The directions refer to which direction the character is facing (a top down perspective) and the numbers(in the object name) refer to the animation state.
Is there anyway for me to be able to "label" the objects (i.e. attach a number to it somehow) so I can use a loop to place them into the arrays?

Comment: Look into a Map of String key/Sprite value pairs.

Comment: Why can't you have one `Sprite` object that holds the 4 different directions? Then you can have get methods for each direction, or a single get method that takes the direction as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a loop like this?

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
  backwardHelmet[i] = new Sprite(16, i, 0, SpriteSheet.armor);
  forwardHelmet[i] = new Sprite(16, i, 1, SpriteSheet.armor);
  rightHelmet[i] = new Sprite(16, i, 2, SpriteSheet.armor);
  leftHelmet[i] = new Sprite(16, i, 3, SpriteSheet.armor);
}
```

You could even assign directions to integers like `backward=0, forward=1, right=2, left=3`and have a multidimensional array and a double for cycle:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
      helmet[i][j] = new Sprite(16, i, j, SpriteSheet.armor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, thank you! I didn't even think to use the coordinates as an identifier (albeit it seems obvious now).  The multidimensional array is very interesting as well (I had no idea!).

Comment: To anyone who may reference this, there is a small error in the solution: the "i++" in the for loop with variable "j" needs to be "j++".

Answer (score 0):

While @AndreaDusza's answer may fit your needs better, if having all of the objects in one array isn't a dealbreaker, you can do it like this:

```
Sprite[] sprites = new Sprite[12];

for( int i = 0 ;  i!=12 ; i++ )
{
   sprites[i] = new Sprite(16, i%3, i/3, SpriteSheet.armor);
}
```

This way:

- 0,1,2 positions are backwards
- 3,4,5 positions are forwards
- 6,7,8 positions are right
- 9,10,11 positions are left